# Get data in SQL RAW query in same format as we get in Laravel with eager loading method

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, raw

I've been working with Laravel Eloquent, now I want to write RAW query and get data with it.

My Query(Eloquent) is this:

```
 $jobs = CompanyJob::where('fair_id',$fair_id);
        
    $jobs = $jobs->with('company');
    // dd($jobs->toSql());
 
    if (!empty($jobIds)) {
      $jobs = $jobs->whereIn('id',$jobIds);
    }
    $jobs = $jobs->orderBy('id', 'ASC');
    if(isset($search) && !empty($search))
      $jobs = $jobs->where(function($query) use($search){
        $query->where('title','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->OrWhere('location','LIKE','%'.$search.'%');
      });

    if (!empty($limit)) {
      $jobs = $jobs->limit($limit);
      $jobs = $jobs->offset($offset);
    }

    $jobs = $jobs->get();
```

The result from this query is :

```
{
    "jobs": [
        {
            "id": 6381,
            "company_id": "1507",
            "fair_id": "118",
            "recruiter_id": "147143",
            "title": "Master of Arts in Entrepreneurship for the Global Hospitality and Tourism Industry",
            "description": "<p><span style=\"font-weight: 400;\">H&auml;r kan du hitta mer information om utbildningen!</span><span style=\"font-weight: 400;\"><br /><br /></span></p>",
            "job_type": "Permanent",
            "language": "English",
            "location": "Brig",
            "contact_name": null,
            "phone": null,
           
            "url": "https://www.studentum.se/skola/swiss-education-group/cesar-ritz-colleges/master-of-arts-in-entrepreneurship-for-the-global-hospitality-and-tourism-industry-969435",
            "salary": "Competitive",
            "match": "1",
            "status": null,
            "params": null,
            "is_imported": "N",
            "questionnaires_template_id": "0",
            "import_ref": null,
            "imported_from": null,
            "match_index": "N",
            "last_offset": null,
            "total_records_to_index": null,
            "created_at": "2021-02-27 17:22:24",
            "updated_at": "2021-02-27 17:22:24",
            "company": {
                "id": 1507,
                "admin_id": null,
                "fair_id": "118",
                "recruiter_id": "147136",
                "company_name": "Swiss Education Group",
              
                "company_post_code": "111",
                "company_state": "Göteborg",
                "company_country": "Sverige",
                "company_match": "1",
                "company_web_url": "https://www.studentum.se/skola/swiss-education-group/",
                "company_facebook_url": null,
                "company_youtube_url": null,
                "company_twitter_url": null,
                "company_in_url": null,
                "company_instagram_url": null,
                "company_stand_type": "Bronze",
                "description": "<p><span style=\"font-weight: 400;\">Vilka &auml;r vi?</span></p>\r\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\r\n<p><span style=\"font-weight: 400;\">Swiss Education Group (SEG) &auml;r en av v&auml;rldens ledande leverant&ouml;rer av Hotell Management, kock -och konditorutbildningar i Schweiz. V&aring;ra utbildningar &auml;r till f&ouml;r studenter som vill ha en internationell karri&auml;r som hotellchef, kock, konditor eller n&aring;got annat yrke inom just servicebranschen.</span></p>\r\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\r\n<p><span style=\"font-weight: 400;\">Vi driver totalt fyra skolor p&aring; olika campus i Schweiz:</span></p>\r\n<p><span style=\"font-weight: 400;\">- Swiss Hotel Management School</span></p>\r\n<p><span style=\"font-weight: 400;\">- Culinary Arts Academy Switzerland</span></p>\r\n<p><span style=\"font-weight: 400;\">- Hotel Institute Montreux</span></p>\r\n<p><span style=\"font-weight: 400;\">- C&eacute;sar Ritz Colleges Switzerland</span></p>\r\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\r\n<p><span style=\"font-weight: 400;\">Samarbeten med branschen</span></p>\r\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\r\n<p><span style=\"font-weight: 400;\">Samtliga skolor som ing&aring;r i v&aring;rt n&auml;tverk, &auml;r akademiskt ackrediterade och har etablerade samarbeten med m&aring;nga av branschens ledande f&ouml;retag och varum&auml;rken. N&aring;gra f&aring; exempel p&aring; samarbeten &auml;r: Four Seasons, Ritz Paris, Marriott International samt lyxrestauranger v&auml;rlden &ouml;ver. Detta ger studenten en utbildning som &auml;r direkt anknuten till vad den internationella hotellbranschen efterfr&aring;gar.</span></p>\r\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\r\n<p><span style=\"font-weight: 400;\">Swiss Education Group (SEG) &auml;r en av v&auml;rldens fr&auml;msta n&auml;tverk av skolor inom 'hospitality management'. N&auml;tverkets framg&aring;ng har lett till att den internationella hotellbranschen nu st&auml;ller allt h&ouml;gre krav p&aring; sina medarbetare. Man kan verkligen s&auml;ga att SEG har h&ouml;jt ribban f&ouml;r kvaliteten p&aring; anst&auml;llda inom hospitality management.</span></p>",
                "company_logo": "assets/images/user-id-48854_SEG-logga.png",
                "company_stand_image": "assets/images/user-id-48854_SEG-logga.png",
                "company_stand_banner": "assets/images/user-id-48854_SEG-roll.jpg",
                "dashboard_thumbnail": null,
                "company_hall": "2",
                "questionnaire_selected": "0",
                "enable_recruiters": "1",
                "enable_webinars": "0",
                "enable_goodies": "0",
                "enable_media": "1",
                "enable_jobs": "1",
                "enable_documents": "1",
                "enable_about": "1",
                "enable_auto_enrolled": "0",
                "enable_poll": "0",
                "display_order": "0",
                "created_at": "2021-02-27 16:59:10",
                "updated_at": "2021-02-27 16:59:10"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 6480,
            "company_id": "1521",
            "fair_id": "118",
            "recruiter_id": "147575",
            "title": "Master of Arts in Entrepreneurship for the Global Hospitality and Tourism Industry",
            "description": "<p><span style=\"font-weight: 400;\">H&auml;r kan du hitta mer information om utbildningen!</span><span style=\"font-weight: 400;\">&nbsp;</span></p>",
            "job_type": "Permanent",
            "language": "English",
            "location": "Brig",
            "contact_name": null,
            "phone": null,
        
            "url": "https://www.studentum.se/skola/swiss-education-group/cesar-ritz-colleges/master-of-arts-in-entrepreneurship-for-the-global-hospitality-and-tourism-industry-969435",
            "salary": "Competitive",
            "match": "1",
            "status": null,
            "params": null,
            "is_imported": "N",
            "questionnaires_template_id": "0",
            "import_ref": null,
            "imported_from": null,
            "match_index": "N",
            "last_offset": null,
            "total_records_to_index": null,
            "created_at": "2021-03-01 00:39:05",
            "updated_at": "2021-03-01 00:39:05",
            "company": {
                "id": 1521,
                "admin_id": null,
                "fair_id": "118",
                "recruiter_id": null,
                "company_name": "Swiss Education Group",
         
                "company_post_code": "111",
                "company_state": "Malmö",
                "company_country": "Sverige",
                "company_match": "1",
                "company_web_url": "https://www.studentum.se/skola/swiss-education-group/",
                "company_facebook_url": null,
                "company_youtube_url": null,
                "company_twitter_url": null,
                "company_in_url": null,
                "company_instagram_url": null,
                "company_stand_type": "Bronze",
                "description": "<p>Vilka &auml;r vi? <br /> <br /> Swiss Education Group (SEG) &auml;r en av v&auml;rldens ledande leverant&ouml;rer av Hotell Management, kock -och konditorutbildningar i Schweiz. V&aring;ra utbildningar &auml;r till f&ouml;r studenter som vill ha en internationell karri&auml;r som hotellchef, kock, konditor eller n&aring;got annat yrke inom just servicebranschen. <br /> <br /> Vi driver totalt fyra skolor p&aring; olika campus i Schweiz: <br /> - Swiss Hotel Management School <br /> - Culinary Arts Academy Switzerland <br /> - Hotel Institute Montreux <br /> - C&eacute;sar Ritz Colleges Switzerland <br /> <br /> Samarbeten med branschen <br /> <br /> Samtliga skolor som ing&aring;r i v&aring;rt n&auml;tverk, &auml;r akademiskt ackrediterade och har etablerade samarbeten med m&aring;nga av branschens ledande f&ouml;retag och varum&auml;rken. N&aring;gra f&aring; exempel p&aring; samarbeten &auml;r: Four Seasons, Ritz Paris, Marriott International samt lyxrestauranger v&auml;rlden &ouml;ver. Detta ger studenten en utbildning som &auml;r direkt anknuten till vad den internationella hotellbranschen efterfr&aring;gar. <br /> <br /> Swiss Education Group (SEG) &auml;r en av v&auml;rldens fr&auml;msta n&auml;tverk av skolor inom 'hospitality management'. N&auml;tverkets framg&aring;ng har lett till att den internationella hotellbranschen nu st&auml;ller allt h&ouml;gre krav p&aring; sina medarbetare. Man kan verkligen s&auml;ga att SEG har h&ouml;jt ribban f&ouml;r kvaliteten p&aring; anst&auml;llda inom hospitality management. <br /> </p>",
                "company_logo": "assets/images/user-id-48854_SEG-logga.png",
                "company_stand_image": "assets/images/user-id-48854_SEG-logga.png",
                "company_stand_banner": "assets/images/user-id-48854_SEG-roll.jpg",
                "dashboard_thumbnail": null,
                "company_hall": "3",
                "questionnaire_selected": "0",
                "enable_recruiters": "1",
                "enable_webinars": "0",
                "enable_goodies": "0",
                "enable_media": "1",
                "enable_jobs": "1",
                "enable_documents": "1",
                "enable_about": "1",
                "enable_auto_enrolled": "0",
                "enable_poll": "0",
                "display_order": "0",
                "created_at": "2021-03-01 00:13:26",
                "updated_at": "2021-03-01 00:13:26"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 6520,
            "company_id": "1528",
            "fair_id": "118",
            "recruiter_id": "147609",
            "title": "Master of Arts in Entrepreneurship for the Global Hospitality and Tourism Industry",
            "description": "<p><span style=\"font-weight: 400;\">H&auml;r kan du hitta mer information om utbildningen!</span> <span style=\"font-weight: 400;\">&nbsp;</span></p>",
            "job_type": "Permanent",
            "language": "English",
            "location": "Brig",
            "contact_name": null,
            "phone": null,
         
            "url": "https://www.studentum.se/skola/swiss-education-group/cesar-ritz-colleges/master-of-arts-in-entrepreneurship-for-the-global-hospitality-and-tourism-industry-969435",
            "salary": "Competitive",
            "match": "1",
            "status": null,
            "params": null,
            "is_imported": "N",
            "questionnaires_template_id": "0",
            "import_ref": null,
            "imported_from": null,
            "match_index": "N",
            "last_offset": null,
            "total_records_to_index": null,
            "created_at": "2021-03-01 01:29:33",
            "updated_at": "2021-03-01 01:29:33",
            "company": {
                "id": 1528,
                "admin_id": null,
                "fair_id": "118",
                "recruiter_id": null,
                "company_name": "Swiss Education Group",
        
                "company_post_code": "111",
                "company_state": "Stockholm",
                "company_country": "Sverige",
                "company_match": "1",
                "company_web_url": "https://www.studentum.se/skola/swiss-education-group/",
                "company_facebook_url": null,
                "company_youtube_url": null,
                "company_twitter_url": null,
                "company_in_url": null,
                "company_instagram_url": null,
                "company_stand_type": "Bronze",
                "description": "<p>Vilka &auml;r vi? <br /> <br /> Swiss Education Group (SEG) &auml;r en av v&auml;rldens ledande leverant&ouml;rer av Hotell Management, kock -och konditorutbildningar i Schweiz. V&aring;ra utbildningar &auml;r till f&ouml;r studenter som vill ha en internationell karri&auml;r som hotellchef, kock, konditor eller n&aring;got annat yrke inom just servicebranschen. <br /> <br /> Vi driver totalt fyra skolor p&aring; olika campus i Schweiz: <br /> - Swiss Hotel Management School <br /> - Culinary Arts Academy Switzerland <br /> - Hotel Institute Montreux <br /> - C&eacute;sar Ritz Colleges Switzerland <br /> <br /> Samarbeten med branschen <br /> <br /> Samtliga skolor som ing&aring;r i v&aring;rt n&auml;tverk, &auml;r akademiskt ackrediterade och har etablerade samarbeten med m&aring;nga av branschens ledande f&ouml;retag och varum&auml;rken. N&aring;gra f&aring; exempel p&aring; samarbeten &auml;r: Four Seasons, Ritz Paris, Marriott International samt lyxrestauranger v&auml;rlden &ouml;ver. Detta ger studenten en utbildning som &auml;r direkt anknuten till vad den internationella hotellbranschen efterfr&aring;gar. <br /> <br /> Swiss Education Group (SEG) &auml;r en av v&auml;rldens fr&auml;msta n&auml;tverk av skolor inom 'hospitality management'. N&auml;tverkets framg&aring;ng har lett till att den internationella hotellbranschen nu st&auml;ller allt h&ouml;gre krav p&aring; sina medarbetare. Man kan verkligen s&auml;ga att SEG har h&ouml;jt ribban f&ouml;r kvaliteten p&aring; anst&auml;llda inom hospitality management. <br /> </p>",
                "company_logo": "assets/images/user-id-48854_SEG-logga.png",
                "company_stand_image": "assets/images/user-id-48854_SEG-logga.png",
                "company_stand_banner": "assets/images/user-id-48854_SEG-roll.jpg",
                "dashboard_thumbnail": null,
                "company_hall": "1",
                "questionnaire_selected": "0",
                "enable_recruiters": "1",
                "enable_webinars": "0",
                "enable_goodies": "0",
                "enable_media": "1",
                "enable_jobs": "1",
                "enable_documents": "1",
                "enable_about": "1",
                "enable_auto_enrolled": "0",
                "enable_poll": "0",
                "display_order": "0",
                "created_at": "2021-03-01 01:19:58",
                "updated_at": "2021-03-01 01:19:58"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to write RAW query for this, first i used **$jobs->toSlq()** but this didn't give me query of **with()**
So I searched and found that for this I have to use

```
DB::enableQueryLog(); and DB::getQueryLog();
```

Then I got following result:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "query" => "select * from `company_jobs` where `fair_id` = ? and (`title` LIKE ? or `location` LIKE ?) order by `id` asc"
    "bindings" => array:3 [
      0 => "118"
      1 => "%the%"
      2 => "%the%"
    ]
    "time" => 4.88
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "query" => "select * from `companies` where `companies`.`id` in (?, ?, ?)"
    "bindings" => array:3 [
      0 => "1507"
      1 => "1521"
      2 => "1528"
    ]
    "time" => 0.27
  ]
]
```

Still I'm not able to understand how to write query to get data as above is given. How will I get companies.id in raw query and how companies record will be join with jobs data etc? Can anyone help me to write Eloquent query in RAW SQL query? I also want to know how **with()** works in Laravel?

**Relations of Models are:**

```
Job->belongsTo('Company') and
Company->hasMany('CompanyJob')
```

Comment: You do the first query alone, THEN you take the results from the first query and run a second one. The eager loading work like that. You get to join table when using `whereHas()`

Comment: how first query and 2nd query results are combined? as you can see in output? with whereHas? if yes how can I combined my raw queries result? any example?

Comment: I also want to know that how can I get company_ids as array from 1st query and pass it to 2nd query ?

Comment: By looping the result with code.

Comment: any code example?

Comment: you may mention the tables and relations between them, this will help in giving you the raw query to get these data using join.

Comment: Thanks for your precious time, I added relations at the end.

Comment: install https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar it will help you to show raw query

Comment: Why do you need to write that query in RAW sql ? you did not explain that part... Also, you can have better code by using [`when`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses) instead of horrible `if`s and `$jobs = new added query`...

Answer (score 1):

Regarding how `with` works, the answer is, the `IN()` SQL statement. The reason you're able to get away with having Model classes relate to eachother despite theoretically using different connections or DB engines is because Laravel doesn't generate `JOIN` statements.
(I've attempted to make it generate true JOINs based on Model configs in the past, and quickly found out things get tricky when trying to keep table-names aliased to keep them unique, but still be able to reference them in the results).

So, `$model->with('relation')` will result in something to the effect of:

```
SELECT * FROM $model::$table;
SELECT * FROM $model->relation()->getTable() WHERE $model->relation()->getKeyName() IN(Model-defined foreign key results from previous query);
```

As for how to actually see the resulting query, I wrote a debug helper that offers just that:
https://gist.github.com/kmuenkel/a6b4e34e5bf6ca44e3c85bf753111850
It's designed to work hand-in-hand with a stack-tract helper, that goes so far as to use Reflection to include field names and default values in the details:
https://gist.github.com/kmuenkel/4a1a8a10e0f68a7e3439c4f612523ec7

Once those are wired up, you just call before you execute your queries. Then call it again at any point afterwards, and dump the results:

```
debug_query();
$model->with(...)->get();
dd(debug_query()->toArray());
```

This will show you all queries executed between points A and B. If, for example, you place them before and after a function call, with queries run somewhere down-stream, and you want to include a trace details *where* the queries are called from, you pull in the DebugTrace code as well, and add `true` as an argument on the point-A function call.

Comment: Nice description 

Comment: Thanks, Can you share raw query or query builder for above given query?(assuming there is no relation declared in models i.e you're not able to get company by $jobs->with('company'); )

Comment: I also want to know that how Laravel gives data such that other query has its own tables data saying company:{ all fields(data) of company} -- you can see example above